# iADs what do i do now and can i get some advice on the app store?

Tags: iad

Hi everyone i was wondering about iAD's. I created a application with them in it but i was wondering what now, do i have to create the ads or does apple populate them for me ? and this will be my first app in the app store any advice. I'm kind of nervous i remember steve saying at the last keynote " This isn't amateur hour" i mean i worked hard on the application ( as hard as a 13 year old using Xcode can work) but i'm not a artist at the images. will they reject my app for images? I'm sorry for all the questions but any advice would defiantly help. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will populate your app with ads. You just need to call the iAd framework correctly and enable iAds when you load the app into the iTunes Connect (there is a button and some extra forms to fill out)